# Android: Using onDoubleTap to draw a circle

Tags: java, android, gesture, ondraw, gesturedetector

I made a  public class that extends ImageView called ZoomInZoomOut. In this view, putting one finger down allows the user to drag the image around. Two fingers pinching in and out allows the user to zoom in or zoom out. These all work fine.

Now I want to double tap to draw a circle at the exact x and y coordinates where the user touches. For some reason the below code does not draw a circle...nothing happens.

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {



    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {


        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(containerWidth,
               containerHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStrokeWidth(2);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmOverlay, matrix, null);
        canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(),event.getY(),
                100, p);

        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing anything with the bitmap after drawing to it. You're also attempting to draw the bitmap onto the canvas that is created from the bitmap.

You should override onDraw and draw your bitmap there while using onDoubleTap to update the bitmap as needed.

Comment: Where should I override onDraw? In the activity that displays the imageView?

Comment: You'll want to create a custom view to handle the drawing in the view directly rather than trying to paint and move the bitmap around. Check out http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: Actually, this MyGestureDetector class is inside of a class that extends ImageView. So should I make another custom view to handle the drawing?

Comment: You could just use the ImageView's onDraw then.